# Declare & implement an iOS method with blocks, but no other parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

Need help declaring and implementing a method with blocks but no parameters.
Sounds simple but I'm missing something because this works:

```
- (void) RetrieveDevices: (NSInteger)count
         success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))success
         failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failure;

- (void)RetrieveDevices:(NSInteger)count
        success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))successBlock
        failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failureBlock
{

}
```

And this won't compile as it's expecting a method body:

```
- (void) RetrieveDevices
             success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))success
             failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failure;

- (void)RetrieveDevices
            success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))successBlock
            failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failureBlock
{

}
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Method names should start with a lowercase letter....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Blocks are parameters. So you want a method signature with two parameters.
Try e.g.:

```
- (void) RetrieveDevicesWithSuccess:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))success
                            failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failure;
```

Comment: What if I wanna combine success and failure into one completion block?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the newline and whitespace between "RetrieveDevices" and "success"/"failure". Try this instead:

```
- (void)RetrieveDevicesOnSuccess:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))successBlock
                       onFailure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failureBlock
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
- (void) RetrieveDevicesSuccess:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *devices))success
                        failure:(void (^)(aylaError *err))failure;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the block syntax, it's the method declaration syntax of the second example.
A method with no parameter is declared as:

```
- (RETURN_TYPE)method_name
```

and a method with parameters is declared as:

```
- (RETURN_TYPE)method_name_part1:(PARAMETER_TYPE1)parameter1 name_part2:(PARAMETER_TYPE2)parameter2...
```

The first example has the correct syntax, with a void return type, and three parameters, the second example has a space after the method name, which is why the compiler expects the body of the method (which he interprets as a no parameter method).

Also note that, by convention, methods names start with a lowercase letter.